# Excel Crashes When Accessing .xlam File

Tags: excel, vba, rpc

I use an XLAM file to store a few subs for general spreadsheet purposes.  The XLAM is added and checked in the VBA editor's references and has worked for 4+ months without any issues.  Most of the functions are pretty basic, like creating PDF's or refreshing connections in whatever spreadsheet calls the subs that reside in the XLAM file.

A few days ago, none of my morning processes ran, and when I checked what happened I had 10 "recovered" files which, when I went to check repairs, Excel said there was nothing wrong with them.  I tried to step through the subs to see where they failed, but each one crashed without an error message from VBA, they just failed completely.  I tried running the macros through a vbs file called from Powershell and I received the message "The remote procedure call failed" on the line which called the macro.

I did not change any code in any of my workbooks or in the XLAM file, nor did I change the references to the XLAM in any way.  In addition, the code consistently works on my co-worker's machines.

I've been calling the functions from the XLAM file as follows:

```
Call Project.Module.Function/Sub(argument)
```

Maybe it is an issue with the RPC but I really do not know, any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm happy to post more code.

Comment: Sometimes VBA code gets corrupted if Excel crashes (even if the issue wasn't with the code). In my experience, the best fix is to save all the coding (copy&past to a text file is preferred over exporting and importing), save the file(s) with the code as XLSX, **close**, reopen, then reinsert the code. If it's the code from the XLAM file (add-in, right?), you may just have to recreate the XLAM.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mistella, I tried your method and I still couldn't seem to get it to work, but I'm going to try it once more just in case I messed up a step.In addition, I noticed that the code works if I edit any of the VBA at all.  So if I run the scripts, it won't work, but if after the first attempt I change the code in any way, either in the add in or in the file that references the add in, it works, or if I re-load the add in.  Again thanks so much for your response.

Comment: What if you change "Is Addin" in the project properties to false, save the XLSM, then change the property to true and re-save as XLAM?

Comment: @Drusch Make sure you close the workbook after saving as ".xlsx". Otherwise it can retain some of the old compiled code, which can cause the issue to be carried into the new version. Same with exporting/importing modules instead of copy&pasting the text - the issue may be carried along. Also, make sure that the code is doing proper "cleanup" (any variable requiring "set" should be set to  either nothing or empty as appropriate at the end of the code, clear/empty/unassign arrays, close out any applications) If too many no-longer-need objects are left floating around, they can also cause issues.

Comment: Also, just remembered, sometimes the issue seemed to stay if I overwrote the old file with the new file. If you're keeping the same name, rename/resave the old file, so the new file isn't overwriting anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mistella, I really appreciate the help and your time.  Also I'm sorry for the delayed response, there was a big industry-wide issue in my field the last couple days and I was distracted from my issue.

I did everything you mentioned but none of it worked!  Luckily I bugged enough people around my company and got a fix.  Someone had a similar issue a few weeks ago and a developer had a fix.  You may know better than me what this is, but I edited the Excel registry with:

“ForceVBALoadFromSource”=dword:00000001

Again thank you so much, I appreciate your help, it means a lot.